# implement jqueryui datepicker into table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement the official [jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) into my playground. The table below contains two cells by row. The datepicker should only appear if clicked in the last date row. Unfortunately I do not receive any error message to work with. Simply nothing happens.

Would you guys help me out with?

**Update:** Its working for the first cell only, as I hardcoded the id in the datepicker. But as soon as I add the counter variable it wouldn´t work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="date-table-wrapper">
        <table id="date-table">
            <tbody>
                <!-- filled by script -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <script>
        var tableDate = document.getElementById("date-table")

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            tableDateRow = `<tr id="row-${i}">
                           <td id="reason-${i}" contenteditable='true'>Something ${i}</td>
                           <td id="date${i}"><input type="text" id="datepicker${i}"></td>
                       </tr>`
            tableDate.innerHTML += tableDateRow
        }

        $(function () {
            var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#date-table td:last-child")
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                $(function () {
                    $("#datepicker0").datepicker();
                });
            }
        })

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you setting a table cell that contains an input field to `contenteditable='true'`? Can't see that making much sense.

Comment: @CBroe old artifacts, you are completely right. Will remove the entry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this specific plugin works but I feel that the jQuery selector `$("datepicker"). (...)` should instead point at the element for which the datepicker should get attached to. So instead of the string `"datepicker"` you should feed it the target element, I think in your scenario it's `$(cells[j]).datepicker()` (note that there are no quotes in the first part of the statement).

Also, if you only want to loop through the last table cells in a row, you should use `td:last-child` in the `querySelectorAll` argument.

There was no error message because the selector `$("datepicker")` tried to find HTML `<datepicker />` elements which obviously don't exist in your document, so it returned no results and the datepicker() method was never executed.

I'm also pretty sure that you shouldn't put that declaration inside of a event handler function, you should just execute it directly in the loop. But it depends on how the plugin works.

Comment: I modified my code, now it only works in the first row. Because its hardcoded. Would not work dynamically.